# How to substract cummulative in SQL from column to column

Tags: sql, percentage

I have this data:

```
Contact  Customers
1        2 
2        3 
3        1 
4        6
```

With a variable which contains the total amount of customers.

This data means that 2 customers had contact with customerservice once, 3 customers had contact with customerservice twice etc.

I'd like to have another column which shows the cummulative percentage of customers contacting the customerservice x times or more. So in this example:

```
Contact  Customers Cumm%
1        2         100
2        3         83.3
3        1         58.3
4        6         50%
```

I've tried several things, but I'm very new to SQL I can't seem to find any examples and going to need some help.

If you know how to get the amount of customers cummulative that'd be fine aswell because I know how to get the percentages. What I mean by this is:

```
Contact  Customers CummCustomers
1        2         12
2        3         10
3        1         7
4        6         6
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a subquery, like this:

```
SELECT
    Contact
,   Customers
,   (SELECT SUM(Customers) FROM myTable t2 WHERE t2.Contact >= t1.Contact) as CummCustomers
FROM myTable t1
```

[Demo on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7190c/2).

Comment: Thanks for your reply but unfortunatly I can't get it to work in my sql statement. Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted... etc

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem by using Analytical query which will be faster.

```
select contact,customer,
sum(customer) over (order by contact desc) cumm_customer
from  table1 order by contact asc;
```

See the sqlfiddle demo here
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/74169/4